# Apache mod_ext_filter and mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy, perl, mod-filter

I have a problem using apache **mod_ext_filter** and **mod_proxy**.

I wrote a per script (add-promo.pl) in order to add some tags to HTML page. My problem is that Apache don't run this script.

I have checked that the proxed response is not zipped.

Can anyone help me or suggest how I can debug this problem?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName 10.1.0.101
   ServerAlias central  192.168.2.2

   ExtFilterDefine promoAdder mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/perl /var/www/cgi-bin/add-promo.pl /tmp/add-promo.out"

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Location "/HM/WS/CatSearch.aspx">
      ProxyPass         http://10.1.0.100/HM/WS/CatSearch.aspx
      ProxyPassReverse  http://10.1.0.100/HM/WS/CatSearch.aspx
      SetOutputFilter   promoAdder
   </Location>

   ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/webapi-core/api
   ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8080/webapi-core/api

   ProxyPass / http://10.1.0.100/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.0.100/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Split the problem in two: does the script run when you run everything related to proxying? Does the proxying work if you remove the script run? Did you try the script just by itself? I am not sure it should write result to a file but to STDOUT instead.